# ImportError: No module named books.models

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django by reading [this book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/index.html) religiously. I'm on chapter 5 : Models, and everything worked fine (in InteractiveConsole) until I reached [Basic Data Access](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05.html#basic-data-access).

```
epqrs@epqrs:~/webapps/djcode/mysite$ pwd
/home/epqrs/webapps/djcode/mysite
epqrs@epqrs:~/webapps/djcode/mysite$ python ../manage.py shell
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:51:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from books.models import Publisher
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named books.models
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/home/epqrs/webapps/djcode', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
>>>
```

I don't get why I get **ImportError: No module named books.models**.
*books* directory lies under the current directory *mysite* (/home/epqrs/webapps/djcode/mysite/books).

Comment: have you put book in your settings INSTALLED_APP?

Comment: Yes, INSTALLED_APPS = ('mysite.books',)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've had to change it to this:

```
from books.models import Publisher, Author, Book
```

So basically, I had to take the `mysite` portion out. 
Also, change installed apps from `'mysite.books'` to just `'books'`

I hope it helps

Comment: I just got to this stage and had the same problem. This worked a treat, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do

```
from mysite.books.models import Publisher
```

to make it work.

Comment: Because in your installed app you put like this ('mysite.books',)

Comment: try only books in installed app then from books.models import Publisher